# formvalidation.io disable validation for entire form

Tags: formvalidation.io

I am using formvalidation.io for our form validation.
Works great if we want to validate the form but we have functionality where we want to allow a user to save a draft of the form. In this scenario we don't want to do validate any part of the form. We don't want to disable each validator we want to disable the entire validation process. I tried using formnovalidate and it worked in Chrome but would not work in IE. What is the best method to do this for all browsers? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant to you, but in case someone else stumbles across it (like I did with a slightly different problem);

We have included the 'novalidate' attribute in the formvalidation initial setup, eg:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is('[novalidate]')) {
        $(this).formValidation({
            //form validation config
        });
    }
});
```